# What are these encrypted Starfield tweets saying?

Tags: cipher, unsolved-mysteries

There are a lot of rumors about Bethesda Softworks and/or Bethesda Game Studios announcing a new game at E3 this year, or even on May 14th ([source](https://youtu.be/iKGAlki4v1Q?t=8m20s)). A key in this mystery is the trademark 'Starfield'. It is speculated that the name of the upcoming game may be 'Starfield'. There was a discovered Twitter account called @StarfieldGame that was created at the same time the trademark was renewed. Additionally, the location of the the twitter user is the same as Bethesda headquarters. This twitter account has a number of mysterious tweets.

https://twitter.com/StarfieldGame

The blanks in the tweet at the top presumably are intended to spell out S T A R F I E L D

What is the message in the (presumably) encrypted tweets?

> S _ _ R _ I E _ _ .....<p a s s. E N C R Y P T>
>
> lcJXk1+7t8Zp+6vrWRr7WyMk8jwrRVkLdoRYPZj3MjIaxEaWgx0PTE6c5YY=
>
> 4OB2/5WjsbarN5pyG3dFBlYTVH0axkhfHTIZGe6Ho7IAp80MLinlM0qOsoINQOkBk+r9Mv3bWRlw
>
> qhqxB/PAKzlnxPY3mF8DFPjKDQntI/UjtQSbCb5JcyBIdEIexrMdcx+AWttsrXl/8vTKznx5dZmB
>
> g6+Glw2zXQ6CXL8pX5Yu5bqXXLqXgoNWtVV0Iuf95Xuy6UVGrM2kjLUMuxHYdxUT1xGoEt/6tHBn
>
> JbST/9CLSP8NrQg4V/8AmaI+k5q0b/JxCgsoSK9XgZR0Xu0EMadXx8c83FxuefSodrteP/h1po+g

[image: Encrypted tweets from @Starfield]

Comment: Just a thought - since Twitter displays tweets in reverse-chronological order, shouldn't the text be presented and interpreted similarly? I.e. starting with `JbST/…` and ending with `c5YY=`?

Comment: that's not unlikely, but we can't really know what order they intended until we know what it says anyway. Since it is known to be reverse chronological, they could have intentionally tweeted in reverse so you read top to bottom. So we dont know until we know

Comment: It's pretty clearly [ROT13](https://www.rot13.com)([onfr64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)) by reading the tweets in reverse, even though that does not decode to anything sensical. This is revealed by the [A-Za-z0-9+/] alphabet, the trailing =, and the 76-character line length.

Comment: when did you grab that screenshot? those tweets are gone now

Comment: The full string in proper order for those interested: `JbST/9CLSP8NrQg4V/8AmaI+k5q0b/JxCgsoSK9XgZR0Xu0EMadXx8c83FxuefSodrteP/h1po+gg6+Glw2zXQ6CXL8pX5Yu5bqXXLqXgoNWtVV0Iuf95Xuy6UVGrM2kjLUMuxHYdxUT1xGoEt/6tHBnqhqxB/PAKzlnxPY3mF8DFPjKDQntI/UjtQSbCb5JcyBIdEIexrMdcx+AWttsrXl/8vTKznx5dZmB4OB/5WjsbarN5pyG3dFBlYTVH0axkhfHTIZGe6Ho7IAp80MLinlM0qOsoINQOkBk+r9Mv3bWRlwlcJXk1+7t8Zp+6vrWRr7WyMk8jwrRVkLdoRYPZj3MjIaxEaWgx0PTE6c5YY=`